# Create a manifest file each time a project is built

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, build-process

I am looking for a way that where each time city creates/starts a build it also creates a manifest file with information about the build like time date, the person who invoked the build etc etc.

Any ideas?

Ww

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Ant, use the `Manifest` task: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/manifest.html

If you are using Maven, configure the Jar plugin to customise the manifest: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/manifest-customization.html

If you're using some other build tool, consult its documentation.

Whichever you use, they can use environment variables set by TeamCity.